# Python - argmax on a histogram

Tags: python, argmax

I'm trying to find peaks on the left and right halves of the image (basically this is a binary image of a road with left and right lanes).
For some reason, the left argmax is giving a value to the right of midpoint, and right is giving beyond the size of the image.

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

binary_warped = cv2.imread('data\Sobel\warped-example.jpg')
histogram = np.sum(binary_warped[binary_warped.shape[0]//2:,:], axis=0)
plt.plot(histogram)
midpoint = np.int(histogram.shape[0]//2)
leftx_base = np.argmax(histogram[:midpoint])
rightx_base = np.argmax(histogram[midpoint:]) + midpoint
print('Shape {} midpoint {} left peak {} right peak {}'.format(histogram.shape, midpoint, leftx_base, rightx_base))
```

This is my input
[image: Binary Warped Image]

Input with shapes on the axis
[image: Input with shapes]

Ideally the left peak should be around 370 and right should be arnd 1000, but
Here is my result

```
Shape (1280, 3) midpoint 640 left peak 981 right peak 1633
```

[image: Result of above code]

Where was the mistake?

Comment: Where does that graph come from? Why do you think the peaks should be around 370 and 1000? Where is the image file you're running this on?

Comment: Hi, I've added the image now, sorry, forgot to include earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The clue is given when you look at the shape of your histogram. It is 2-dimensional as it has a shape of `(1280, 3)`

When you call `np.argmax(histogram[:midpoint])`, `argmax` is called on a 2-d array and will first be unraveled before finding the largest value/index

You can see an example of this in the numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.argmax(a)
5
```